# Unloading a data reference in Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

Currently I am struggling with a Entity Framework issue.  I have a wcf service that sits on top of the ef framework, and allows queries to the framework.  At some point the user is able to request a file from the framework.  The files are referenced by solution entries, so when you request a file from a solution, the reference is loaded to gain access to the file store.

That all works fine, but from that point onward, whenever you do another query that returns that solution entry, the whole file gets attached to the return result.  I need some way of detaching or unloading the reference, such that the result entries will only contain an unloaded reference to the file store again.

I have tried to create a new context and query that context to retrieve information from, but when I do that, the entity in the original context is also changed.

I have tried to detach the entity from the original context and then query from the new context.  That does not work either.

I have found one way of doing this.  For all the non file-download queries, I detach the result entity, and send that over the wire.  I am not sure if that is the best way to go about it though.

I hope someone might be able to provide some insight, thanks for the effort.

Comment: can you clarify how you are hosting the WCF service (self hosted or IIS hosted) and explain what you mean by solution reference included with the files (how are the reference related to the files).

Comment: The site is IIS hosted and the references are related to the files because of Entity Framework. The files are in a separate table but linked to the information tables via an external key. So to access the linked entity from the information table, you have to load the file reference. Once the lazy loading takes place, you cannot unmount the link.

Comment: Do you mean all files are in the database, and that you have an entity type for the files? If so, when you say you've tried to detach entities, is that "solution" entities or file entities? The latter should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is probably do to **Change Tracking**, which is on by default.

**Possible Solution:**

Disable Change Tracking with [MergeOption.NoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx)

```
using (MyEntities _context = new MyEntities())
{
    _context.Widgets.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

    return _context.Widgets.ToList();

}
```

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx) may help to point you in the right direction on how to handle this issue if the solution above does not work.

I struggled with a similar issue recently. The problem was the result of the context maintaining a reference to the object I was using (obviously). Every time I made a change to an object of the same type, even when obtained with a new context (so I thought), the object was being changed.

With help from one of my peers, we determined the context was hanging around due to the way I was registering it with my IoC container (lifestyle per web request). When I changed the lifestyle to transient (which definitively provided a new instance) then changes to objects of the same type were unaffected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: LOL...man...didn't realize you asked this question over 2yrs ago! I'm sure you solved this issue by now =) Hopefully the answer will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks Rich. I will definately try it out. I think in the end I just stuck to the "solution" mentioned in the question but this might very well teach me something new. :D